# Parse JSON on javascript after return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(json) [.NET handler]

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json, parsing, javascriptserializer

i'm developing an web application in .net platform.

i have wrote an Handler code that return a JSON object to Javascript (after i request in AJAX).

the Handler code:

```
var wrapper = new { 
    left = left.ToString(), 
    top = top.ToString(), 
    width = width.ToString(), 
    height = height.ToString() };
context.Response.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(wrapper));
```

In Javascript, when i do alert, i see that i get an object. and it's good.
But now i want to parse it to JSON.

when i do `JSON.parse(msg);` i get an error

> "JSON.parse: unexpected character"

when i do `jQuery.parseJSON(msg);` using jquery-1.6.2, i get this error

> jQuery.parseJSON is not a function (i'm using jquery-1.6.2)

What is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

Create a page called TestPage.aspx like this.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Test Page</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'TestPage.aspx/GetDimensions',
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: '{}',
                success: function (response) {
                    // Don't forget that the response is wrapped in a
                    //  ".d" object in ASP.NET 3.5 and later.
                    var data = response.d;
                    $('#test-div').animate({
                        left: data.left + 'px',
                        top: data.top + 'px',
                        height: data.height + 'px',
                        width: data.width + 'px'
                    }, 5000, function () {
                        // Animation complete.
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        #test-div
        {
            background-color:#eee;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            border-radius: 5px;
            height: 100px;
            left:0px;
            padding-top: 40px;
            text-align:center;
            top:0px;
            width: 100px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

    <div id="test-div">
    This is a test div
    </div>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And on TestPage.aspx.cs, do this

```
using System.Web.Services;

public partial class Test1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){/*page load eent*/}

    static int left = 50;
    static int top = 50;
    static int height = 200;
    static int width = 200;

    [WebMethod]
    public static object GetDimensions()
    {
        return new
        {
            left = left.ToString(),
            top = top.ToString(),
            width = width.ToString(),
            height = height.ToString()
        };
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Courtesy: [ASP.NET web services mistake: manual JSON serialization by Dave Ward](http://encosia.com/asp-net-web-services-mistake-manual-json-serialization/)

Comment: JavaScriptSerializer is available on ASP.NET 3.5 as well.

Comment: @Mehdi Golchin: wasn't sure and was too lazy to check MSDN. thank you. updated :)

Comment: Thank you very much! ill try and let you know :)

Comment: hey, i did what you told me to do. 
now i'm getting the following error:
 Object doesn't support property or method 'parseJSON'

Comment: i will knock up a small example when i get time

Comment: You can eliminate the $.parseJSON and manual JavaScriptSerializer steps here.  Set the method's return type to object or dynamic and return the anonymous type directly. More info: http://encosia.com/asp-net-web-services-mistake-manual-json-serialization/

Comment: @dave: i have read that but i am unable to do so because i get them inside a key/value pair wrapper. i am using *Accepting an object from the client-side*

Comment: I just tested returning the anonymous type directly with a method return type of `object` and got this: `{"d":{"left":50,"top":50,"height":200,"width":200}}`  Are you seeing something different?

Comment: thanks dave. i have updated the answer. this auto serialization was new for me.